# How to properly use sendResponse() in MV3 Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm playing around with Promises available in Chrome extensions Manifest V3, but I'm not getting the expected results. What I'm trying to achieve: store some data from a browser action popup, then get a response back after the data is saved. Here's what I have so far:

**background.js (service worker)**

```
async function handleMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch (message.request) {
    case 'setTimestamp':
      await chrome.storage.local.set(message.data);
      sendResponse({
        status: chrome.runtime.lastError ? 'error' : 'ok'
      });
      break;
    default:
      sendResponse(null);
  }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
```

**popup.js**

```
// Event handler for button in popup.html
async function setTimestamp() {
  const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    request: 'setTimestamp',
    data: {
      timestamp: performance.now()
    }
  });
  console.log('setTimestamp response', response);
}
```

The timestamp is being saved successfully, but the response in popup.html is `undefined` instead of `{status: 'ok'}` that I was expecting. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

(Note: I'm aware you can use `storage.local.set()` directly from the popup and validate that the data was saved successfully by detecting `chrome.runtime.lastError` in the callback, but I wanted to use the new aync/await pattern above.)

Comment: TLDR: there are two bugs in Chrome here. One (awaiting sendMessage) is fixed in Chrome 99, another one (using async onMessage) may take a long time to be fixed so use a separate async function or embed an async IIFE.